# How do I force session timeout or a logout of a user when the app auto saves in an asp.net mvc 2 application?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've seen this question asked a few ways and the solutions are generally for other languages and don't apply to ASP.NET MVC 2.

I am using Jquery & Jquery forms to auto-save user data at a set interval. I still want the application to be able to time out, but the auto-saves via jquery forms keep refreshing the server.

My initial idea to fix this was pretty simple. I've already got an ActionFilter I use to see if the session expires. Well, the session won't ever expire; however, I just keep track of how many auto saves occurr based on a value in session and when it reaches a limit (specified in the web.config), it does a:

```
 filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account.aspx/LogOn");
```

Well, this doesn't work because the auto save is doing an ajaxFormSubmit to call the action in the first place. I've tried changing the action to redirect to the login page, but the same thing happens....it just doesn't do a redirect. The only thing the action can return is a Json result. In my latest version (code below) I'm setting the json return value to false and calling a redirectToLogin() function to send the page over to the login page. It doesn't work and i'm not sure why.

Any thoughts on this would be most helpful.

Excerpt of code that sets up the interval for autosaving on the view (placed just before the form is closed):

```
<%
    double sessionTimeoutInMinutes = double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SESSION_TIMEOUT_IN_MINUTES"].ToString());
    double maxContiguousAutoSaves = double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MAX_CONTIGUOUS_AUTO_SAVES"].ToString());           
    double autoSaveInterval = (sessionTimeoutInMinutes / maxContiguousAutoSaves) * 60 * 1000;               
%>

    <%= Html.Hidden("autoSaveInterval", autoSaveInterval) %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var autoSaveFrequency = $('[id=autoSaveInterval]').val();
            //alert(' Auto Save Interval in miliseconds: ' + autoSaveFrequency);                
            setInterval(
                "initAutoSave('AutoSaveGoals', 'message')"
                , autoSaveFrequency);
        });

    </script>
```

"AutoSaveGoals" goals is the name of one of my actions. It handles the post, updates certain items in session, and calls the repository.update. It is defined below:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AutoSaveGoals(Data data)
    {
        Data sessdata = Data();
        sessdata.MpaGoals = data.Goals;
        sessdata.MpaStatus = data.MpaStatus;
        sessdata.StartPeriodDate = data.StartPeriodDate;
        sessdata.EndPeriodDate = data.EndPeriodDate;
        sessdata.AssociatePassword = data.AssociatePassword;

        try
        {
            _repository.update(sessdata);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogUtil.Write("AutoSaveGoals", "Auto Save Goals Failed");
            LogUtil.WriteException(e);
        }

                    if (!autoLogOffUser(RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")))
            return Json(new { success = true });
        else
            return Json(new { success = false });

    }
```

The initAutoSave function is javascript that uses Jquery & Jquery Forms plugin. Here it is:

```
function initAutoSave(targetUrl, messageDivId) {
    var options = {
        url: targetUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            //alert('Returned from save! data: ' + data);
            if (data.success) {
                var currDateAndTime = " Page last saved on: " + getCurrentDateAndTime();
                $('[id=' + messageDivId + ']').text(currDateAndTime).show('normal', function() { })
            }
            else {
                alert('redirecting to login page');
                redirectToLogin();
                //$('[id=' + messageDivId + ']').text(' An error occurred while attempting to auto save this page.').show('normal', function() { })
                //alert('ERROR: Page was not auto-saved properly!!!!');
            }
        }
    };
    $('form').ajaxSubmit(options);
}
```

I try doing a javascript redirect in redirectToLogin() but it doesn't seem to get the url or something behind the scenes is blowing up. Here is how it's defined:

```
function redirectToLogin() {    
    window.location = "Account.aspx/LogOn";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this is just absurd...So, I was looking over my applications (I've got several going to QA soon) and noted that I've already solved this very question with a much better solution - it was ALL handled in an ActionFilter. I wanted this from the getgo when I asked this question, but to have already implemented it, forgot about that, AND ask again on Stack Overflow...well, I hope my memory issues helps somebody with this. Below is the full action filter code. As always, I'm open to criticism so mock it, revise it, copy it, etc, etc.

```
public class UserStillActiveAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        int sessionTimeoutInMinutes = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SESSION_TIMEOUT"].ToString());
        int maxContiguousAutoSaves = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MAX_CONSEC_SAVES"].ToString());
        int autoSaveIntervalInMinutes = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AUTO_SAVE_INTERVAL"].ToString());

        string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

        HttpContext currentSession = HttpContext.Current;      

        LogAssociateGoalsSessionStatus(filterContext.HttpContext, actionName);

        if (actionName.ToLower().Contains("autosave"))
        {
            int autoSaveCount = GetContigousAutoSaves(filterContext.HttpContext);
            if (autoSaveCount == maxContiguousAutoSaves)
            {
                var result = new RedirectResult("~/Account.aspx/LogOff");
                if (result != null && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    //Value checked on Logon.aspx page and message displayed if not null
                    filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add(PersistenceKeys.SessionTimeOutMessage,
                        StaticData.MessageSessionExpiredWorkStillSaved);

                        string destinationUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(
                                                result.Url,
                                                filterContext.HttpContext);
                    filterContext.Result = new JavaScriptResult()
                    {
                        Script = "window.location='" + destinationUrl + "';"
                    };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RefreshContiguousAutoSaves(filterContext.HttpContext, autoSaveCount + 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            RefreshContiguousAutoSaves(filterContext.HttpContext, 1);
        }

    }

    private int GetContigousAutoSaves(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        Object o = context.Session[PersistenceKeys.ContiguousAutoUpdateCount];
        int contiguousAutoSaves = 1;

        if (o != null && int.TryParse(o.ToString(), out contiguousAutoSaves))
        {
            return contiguousAutoSaves;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    private void RefreshContiguousAutoSaves(HttpContextBase context,
                                            int autoSavecount)
    {
        context.Session.Remove(PersistenceKeys.ContiguousAutoUpdateCount);
        context.Session.Add(PersistenceKeys.ContiguousAutoUpdateCount,
                                    autoSavecount);
    }

    private void LogAssociateGoalsSessionStatus(HttpContextBase filterContext, string actionName)
    {
        AssociateGoals ag = (AssociateGoals)filterContext.Session[(PersistenceKeys.SelectedAssociateGoals)];
        bool assocGoalsIsNull = false;
        bool assocGoalsInformationIsNull = false;

        if (ag == null)
        {
            assocGoalsIsNull = true;
            assocGoalsInformationIsNull = true;
        }
        else if (ag != null && ag.AssociateInformation == null)
            assocGoalsInformationIsNull = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

best way to solve this is to have your code always return an Json result,    i use a model called StandardAjaxResponse that has an ID, a Message and an answer   answer is always false unless my code completes in the correct way and sets this to true.  Any errors from try / catch   are placed into the message field,  so if !data.Answer  and the Message is equal to not loggged in the you can then location.href to the login page, without getting the login page as your ajax response.

for example:

```
public class AjaxGenericResponse{
    public bool Answer {get;set; }
    public int Id {ge; set; } // this is for cases when i want an ID result
    public string Mesage {get;set;}  // this is so i can show errors from ajax
}
```

the controller / action

```
public JsonResult DoAutoSave(Data data){
    var JsonResults = new AjaxGenericResponse{Answer=false};

    // do code here to save etc
    // no matter what always return a result, even if code is broken
    return Json(model);
 }
```

your Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"",
    dataTYpe: 'json',
    success:function(data){
        if(data.Answer) {
            // all is good
         } else {
            if(data.Message === "logout') {  href.location=('login'); } else { alert(data.Message); }
         }

    }
});
```

thats one solution anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. Thanks for your response minus, but I think our solutions coincided for the answer. My issue was I didn't have the right url to redirect to in the redirectToLogin method. I've made minor tweaks, and presto, its redirecting.

**Javascript changes:**

```
function redirectToLogin(url) {    
    window.location = url;
}

function initAutoSave(targetUrl, messageDivId) {
    var options = {
        url: targetUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            //alert('Returned from save! data: ' + data);
            if (data.success) {
                var currDateAndTime = " Page last saved on: " + getCurrentDateAndTime();
                $('[id=' + messageDivId + ']').text(currDateAndTime).show('normal', function() { })
            }
            else {
                alert('redirecting to login page');
                redirectToLogin(data.url);
                //$('[id=' + messageDivId + ']').text(' An error occurred while attempting to auto save this page.').show('normal', function() { })
                //alert('ERROR: Page was not auto-saved properly!!!!');
            }
        }
    };
    $('form').ajaxSubmit(options);
}
```

**Action changes**

```
    if (!shouldAutoLogOffUser(RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")))
        return Json(new { success = true, url = "" });
    else
        return Json(new { success = false , url = Url.Action("LogOff","Account").ToString() });
```

The shouldAutoLogOffUser checks a session variable that was updated by an action filter to track the # of contiguous auto saves and handles the logic to see if that value has exceeded the max # of contiguous autosaves allowed. The action filter checked the actionname for 'AutoSave' and if it found it, the counter was incremented. Otherwise the counter was reset to 0 (a non autosave post occurred).

One more random question. If this application were loaded in an IFrame and the window.location call is made, would the IFrame content be changed or the entire page (the container in essence) be changed? Our company is looking to run some of our asp.net mvc 2 apps in IFrame's via websphere portal (yeah, I know....it's not my choice).

Comment: yes mate, end of day its about extending that model as much as you need but always delivering it and therefor avoiding issues where you get login pages or error pages within your ajax results as for your iframe its iframID.window.loaction.href  if i remember rightly havent used an iframe in like 10 years :-))

Answer (score 0):

always use double quote in java script  and jquery to avoid browser specific issues

like

dataTYpe: 'json' must be as "dataTYpe:"json"